# How can I remove the Unicode u from a JSON item?

Tags: python, json, string, unicode

```
>>> stuff = '[["hiya"]]'
>>> js = json.loads(stuff)
>>> js[0]
[u'hiya']
>>> str(js[0])
"[u'hiya']"
```

It doesn't seem to go away. How can I print `hiya` on its own (without manually stripping the special characters away)?

Comment: Do you want to print `hiya`, or `['hiya']` (`js[0]` is a list, not a string)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a list that's nested two levels deep. Try it like this to simply print 'hiya':

```
>>> import json
>>> stuff = '[["hiya"]]'
>>> js = json.loads(stuff)
>>> str(js[0][0])
'hiya'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is use maping and join to convert a list to string. but i not recommend you to use this but you can use when you need directly convert list to a string. othrewise above solution is fine.

for eg.

```
import json

stuff = '[["hiya"]]'

js = json.loads(stuff)

print ''.join(map(str,js[0]))
```